# how to stop validating numbers stats with zero (0) in php

Tags: php

I am making a php form. I want to validate numerical content in PHP. I am using this PHP code for do it.

```
if (!preg_match('/^[0-9]*$/',$id)) 
{
    $id_Err = "Only numbers allowed";
}
```

But this code allows numbers starts with 0.

```
ex:- 01,02,.....,0100...
```

I only need to allow nubers like

```
1,2,....100,...
```

How can I write this regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work.

```
if (!preg_match('/^[1-9][0-9]*$/',$id)) 
{
    $id_Err = "Only numbers allowed";
}
```

It forces the regex to match a number from `1-9`, and then 0 or more of any digit. This will watch any positive integer greater than zero.

If you want to allow a single zero as well:

```
if (!preg_match('/^(?:[1-9][0-9]*)$|^0$/',$id)) 
{
    $id_Err = "Only numbers allowed";
}
```